# Cannot update new kernel for CentOS 7 although the server have space enough

Tags: centos, kernel, linux-kernel

I try to update kernel on my CentOS 7 but the `yum` say there is no space enough on `/boot` although `/boot` have 343 MB as show below:

Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on

```
/dev/sda2 477M 105M 343M 24% /boot
```

Here the error that I got:

Transaction check error:

```
installing package kernel-3.10.0-123.9.2.el7.x86_64 needs 30MB on the
/boot filesystem
```

That's weird.

Comment: Can you add full output of `du -h`?

Comment: @kirill-a What do you want it for?

Comment: There may be not enough memory for Yum update on tmpfs or your / mount but he can display incorrect message about /boot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rebooting the system, and then trying installing the kernel update again? If that doesn't work, this could be a bug unless it actually requires 373 MB to install the kernel.

```bsh
yum install yum-utils<br>
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2
```

Second command of `package-cleanup` would leave latest 2 kernels in the server.

It says 30 more MB space for installation of the kernel.

Comment: @Michiel        I have only one kernel,3.10 version

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `/boot` mounted readonly, by chance? If so,

```
mount -o rw,remount /boot &&
yum update kernel &&
mount -o ro,remount /boot
```

(note: I'm rarely seen at centos hosts being an ALT Linux developer so YMMV)